# jtweets anywhere filter our multiple tweets from the same user if they are consecutive

Tags: javascript, twitter

Hello I am using jtweetsanywhere in this website [creativosencordoba](http://creativosencordoba.com) which shows my list of local creatives' twitter accounts. I would like to limit the number of consecutive tweets made by the same user so the list would show diversity rather than a monotone from the same user.

I think it can be done using the filter feature, but I am not sure how to start… Would really appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction. many thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your can find tweetFilter samples [here](http://jsdo.it/tbillenstein/jQRz) and [here](https://github.com/tbillenstein/jTweetsAnywhere/issues/2).